# Rack Equipment that is Non-Integer Rack Units Tall

Tags: rack, rackmount

I came across these two items of non-integer rack unit height:
1. [This rack mount kit](http://www.cablesandkits.com/cisco-asa5505-rack-mount-kit-p-1415.html) which seems to be trying to make the best of the slightly-taller-than-1U form factor of the [Cisco ASA5505](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000O0Z8GC).
2. [This 1.5U Server Case](http://www.aicipc.com/1.5U.aspx) that espouses the merits of a case height between 1RU and 2RU.

My questions are as follows:

A. (1) seems to protrude 1/8 RU above and below the rack unit it is bolted in.  Is there any way to make use of the 7/8 RU remaining above and below?  Or would using that bracket effectively consume 3 RU?

B. Are there any gotchas I should be aware of (like rack rail bolt patterns not working out, etc) when I consider one of these non-integer RU server cases like (2)?

Comment: +1. Some Ciscos 2970 and 3550 and 3750 are 1.5RU tall and that's not really convenient in most deployments.

Comment: Odd.  But I guess 2 x 1.5U = 3U?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're supposed to use the 1.5 rack-unit equipment in pairs... But that's really a nonstandard setup.

For the Cisco ASA 5505, it's really a desktop/tabletop SOHO device. When I use them in data centers or rack setups, [I usually place them on a shelf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVuKo.jpg) (which is usually a fraction of a rack-unit as well). *Nobody* uses a rackmount kit for that device... Well, maybe, but I have yet to see one in the field.

Comment: You just beat me to the same answer :-) Place on a shelf or combine with other non-standard stuff. (KVM's, networked USB hubs, modems, etc.) Don't be tempted to mount this stuff 1 hole lower or higher than an integral unit. Sooner or later things get ugly that way.